# Android UDP packet padding to 60 bytes

Tags: android, udp, padding

I'm trying to communicate with third-party device via UDP on my Android tablet. I need to send only 4 bytes. But in Wireshark I see that packet was added by 00 (zeros).

- Android: Data size 4 bytes, Packet size 60 bytes. Device does not
  respond.
- Windows: Data size 4 bytes, Packet size 46 bytes. Everything    works
  fine.

Is there a way to get rid of padding zeros?

Tablet: Google Nexus 10, Android 5.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add code you have tried.

If I understand your question, what you want is

```
byte[] buff = new byte[recv_packet.getLength()];
System.arraycopy(recv_packet.getData(), 0, buff, 0, buff.length);
```

Beeing recv_packet the datagrampacket set on socket.receive(recv_packet)